# cURL proxy reverso

Tags: php, libcurl

A minha cURL requisita uma informação em um servidor (Youtube). Mas para que eu tenha a resposta desejada, a requisição deveria ser feita com o IP de uma usuária, ao invés do meu.

Como faço para entregar o conteúdo direto ao usuário sem que o meu servidor precise intermediar o download?

Seria possível fazer isso com proxy, ou teria que ser outra solução?

Eu editei a cURL do [Script YouTube-Downloader](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader)  mas não deu certo.

```
function curlGet($URL) {

    $proxy=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].":80";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 3;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $URL );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , $timeout );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

    /* if you want to force to ipv6, uncomment the following line */ 
    //curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE , 'CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE_V6');
    $tmp = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $tmp;
}
```

O que estaria errado?

Comment: Poste o erro que ocorre, a sua duvida pode ser clara pra você que esta com a maquina que tem o proxy, mas não é clara pras demais pessoas, a unica maneira de se fazer entender o problema é dizer o que exatamente esta falhando amigo. Edite a pergunta e forneça os detalhes pro entendimento do problema. Tenho certeza que vai entender isto como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4520

Answer (score 5):

O cURL vai efetuar uma requisição HTTP para o servidor, e obter a resposta dele. Observe que isso é uma via de duas mãos, pois em cada conexão alguns dados são enviados e depois recebidos. O cURL usa o HTTP, que por sua vez usa o TCP e que por sua vez usa o IP.

No TCP, é estabelecida uma conexão conhecida como *three-way handshake* (em tradução livre, isso seria como "aperto de mãos em três vias"). Neste procedimento, o cliente envia um pacote para se conectar ao servidor (SYN), o servidor envia um pacote confirmando o aceite da conexão (SYN-ACK) e o cliente também envia um pacote confirmando tudo (ACK) ao servidor. Esse procedimento só é possível se houver uma comunicação de duas vias.

Após finalizado o *three-way handshake*, de acordo com o TCP, tanto o cliente quanto o servidor podem enviar ou receber pacotes a vontade. Entretanto, no caso do HTTP, essa troca de pacotes ocorre de forma que o cliente envia uma requisição (constituída de um cabeçalho e em alguns casos um corpo) e o servidor, após receber a requisição e decidir o que fazer com ela, envia uma resposta (também constituída de um cabeçalho e um corpo). Após o servidor enviar a resposta, ele pode encerrar a conexão com o cliente ou aguardar mais requisições.

Todo o processo do *three-way handshake*, do envio da requisição do cliente e da resposta do servidor ocorre por meio de pacotes IP. Porém, para que a conexão funcione, o servidor vai precisar do endereço IP de quem está estabelecendo a conexão a fim de poder concluir o processo do *three-way hand-shake* e depois enviar a resposta da requisição (e ele possivelmente vai olhar o endereço IP do remetente da requisição na hora de formular a resposta). Se você forjar os pacotes da conexão TCP usando um endereço de IP que não é seu (o que é possível e é algo que muitos hackers fazem), o processo do *three-way hand-shake* não poderá ser concluído com sucesso, pois o servidor enviará o SYN-ACK e tentará estabelecer a conexão com um endereço que não é o seu.

Em teoria, você poderia realizar o processo forjando o endereço IP da sua usuária e então interceptar os pacotes que o servidor envia a fim de estabelecer a conexão e poder obter a resposta de forma adequada, finjindo ser a usuária. Mas neste caso, você teria que ter controle de alguns dos pontos do roteamento de pacotes entre o servidor e a sua usuária a fim de interceptá-los. E neste caso, você já acabou criando uma espécie de proxy ou NAT para resolver o seu problema.

---

Editado.

Em resposta a esses comentários:

> É isso mesmo que eu quero, só que no caso eu não vou interceptar os dados, o usuário vai receber direto os dados.

> Para ser mais claro da uma olhada nesse site convert2mp3.net Ele faz download de vídeos do youtube, mas de alguma forma que eu desconheço, ele autentica com o ip do usuário.

Se o que você quer é simplesmente iniciar a conexão em lugar da usuária e fazer ela receber a resposta sem ter se conectado ao servidor ou sem estar ciente disso de alguma outra forma, então esquece, não vai funcionar. O motivo é que a usuária não terá a conexão aberta com o servidor, então os pacotes TCP recebidos por ela serão descartados. O que acontece é mais ou menos o seguinte:

1. Você que tem o IP 1.2.3.4 que conecta no servidor 5.6.7.8 na porta 80. Entretanto, você usa o IP forjado 9.10.11.12 nos pacotes, e esse IP pertence a usuária. No protocolo TCP, uma porta TCP será alocada no cliente para isso. Vamos supor que a porta que o seu sistema operacional tenha escolhido (ou que você mesmo tenha escolhido ao forjar o pacote) seja a 9876. Assim você terá um pacote IP do tipo SYN tendo como origem a porta 9876 do IP 9.10.11.12 e como desstino a porta 80 do IP 5.6.7.8.
2. O servidor recebe o SYN e designará alguma porta TCP livre do lado dele. Vamos dizer que seja a porta 43210. Assim o servidor envia o SYN-ACK tendo como origem a porta 43210 do IP 5.6.7.8 e como destino a porta 9876 do IP 9.10.11.12. Neste processo, o servidor reservará a porta 43210 para uso exclusivo da porta 9876 do IP 9.10.11.12, descartando qualquer outro pacote que chegue nesta porta vindo de algum outro lugar que não seja a porta 9876 de 9.10.11.12. Ao enviar o SYN-ACK, o servidor também espera que a porta 9876 de 9.10.11.12 fique reservada para uso exclusivo de sua porta 43210.
3. Se a usuária receber um SYN-ACK na porta 9876 vindo da porta 43210 do IP 5.6.7.8, vai ocorrer um erro no TCP, pois não haverá nenhum processo no sistema operacional de lá esperando algo nessa porta. E se houver,
   algo ouvindo usando a porta 9876, esse algo não vai estar esperando pacotes SYN-ACK da porta 43210 do IP 5.6.7.8. Como resultado, o SYN-ACK será descartado.
4. Se você quiser, pode interceptar esse SYN-ACK (independente do fato de ele também ter sido encaminhado para a usuária ou não) e enviar um ACK para a porta 43210 do IP 5.6.7.8, e logo em seguida mandar o conteúdo da requisição.
5. O servidor recebe o ACK e o(s) pacote(s) com a requisição, processa os dados, e envia a resposta para a porta 9876 do IP 9.10.11.12.
6. A usuária recebe alguns pacotes de dados na porta 9876 vindos da porta 43210 do IP 5.6.7.8. Como não haverá nada nessa porta (ou nada que esteja esperando pacotes da porta 43210 de 5.6.7.8), então os pacotes são descartados.

Neste caso, as suas opções são:

- Fazer um sistema mais complicado, aonde há um serviço rodando no host da usuária e quando você fizer o cURL para o servidor, o servidor faz um cURL para a usuário enviando-lhe dados. Entretanto, neste caso você tem que ter a possibilidade de deixar um programa esperando conexões na usuária e o servidor tem que ser capaz de alcançá-la. Você não pode fazer isso com o convert2mp3.net.
- Abandonar o TCP e usar UDP ao invés disso. No UDP, quaisquer pacotes que chegam em uma determinada porta acabam aceitos, não importando a origem ou o conteúdo. Entretanto, novamente tanto o servidor quanto a usuária vão precisar de um programa especial para isso e você terá que implementar medidas de segurança você mesmo para evitar que um atacante se aproveite disso. Você não pode fazer isso com o convert2mp3.net.
- Fazer a usuária realizar periodicamente um processo de *polling* no servidor a procura de alguma coisa que tenha sido postada por você. Você não pode fazer isso com o convert2mp3.net.
- Estabelecer a conexão com o servidor e com a usuária e redirecionar o que for recebido do servidor para a usuária. Neste caso você vai ter criado algo similar a um proxy ou NAT.
- Colocar algum processo no sistema operacional da usuária que sob o seu comando, estabeleça ela mesma todas as etapas do processo de conexão TCP, inclusive o download de todos os pacotes da resposta.
- Fazer com que o sistema da usuária aceite os pacotes vindos do servidor. Entretanto nesse caso, talvez seria mais fácil fazer com que ela mesma iniciasse a conexão, tal como na alternativa anterior.

E por fim, o processo que autentica o IP do usuário é relativamente simples: O IP de origem está embutido no pacote IP e a porta de origem no pacote TCP (que está dentro do pacote IP). O servidor ao receber esse pacote IP, tem acesso a todo o seu conteúdo, inclusive o endereço IP de origem. O servidor pode usar o endereço IP de origem para decidir se atende ou não a requisição e como a atenderá. O servidor não tem como saber se esse IP de origem é verdadeiro, mas responderá nele e se os pacotes de resposta acabarem sendo roteados para alguém que não está esperando por eles, não vai dar certo.

Leitura recomendada: [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) e [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol).

Comment: É isso mesmo que eu quero, só que no caso eu não vou interceptar os dados, o usuário vai receber direto os dados.

Comment: Para ser mais claro da uma olhada nesse site http://convert2mp3.net/ 
Ele faz download de vídeos do youtube, mas de alguma forma que eu desconheço, ele autentica com o ip do usuário.

Comment: @RafaeldeOliveira Resposta editada

Comment: Bom, pra você entender melhor o que eu quero ai vai.

Comment: https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader

Esse ai é o script que eu estou usando, ele funciona legal, mais no servidor quando um usuária requisita o download, o yutube autentica com ip do servidor , isso é ruim por que se haver uma grande demanda de requisição, o youtube vai limitar os downloads.

O que você acha a alguma solução para isso, independente de proxy, curl, enfim, algo que funcione como convert2mp3.net e não com ele propriamente dito.

Comment: @RafaeldeOliveira **Agora sua pergunta já se tornou algo totalmente diferente, e recomendo postar uma outra pergunta.** Entretanto, a minha ideia seria usar o YouTube Downloader para baixar o vídeo direto para a sua máquina, subir um servidor HTTP na sua máquina que disponibilize o vídeo recém baixado, acessar o convert2mp3.net via cURL ou via selenium e colocar a URL do seu servidor local, deixar o convert2mp3.net fazer o download a partir da sua máquina enquanto você faz o download deles. A parte ruim é que o vídeo acaba trafegando duas vezes na sua rede e a música três vezes.

Comment: @RafaeldeOliveira Espera, o que você quer é publicar um site estilo youtube downloader aonde o usuário do seu site baixe os vídeos localmente sem que todo o tráfego tenha que passar pelo seu site? É isso?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo.

Comment: @RafaeldeOliveira **Poste outra pergunta deixando isso claro.** Nesta daqui você pediu para fazer uma requisão no cURL e perguntou se poderia evitar de usar um proxy, sendo que o que você queria na verdade é fazer um youtube downloader que entregasse o conteúdo direto ao usuário sem que o seu servidor precisasse intermediar o download. Observe que você acabou fazendo uma pergunta que não era a que você queria e no fim das contas nem era parecida!

Comment: ok entendi, agora mesmo eu vou fazer outra pergunta.
Obrigado.

Comment: Desculpa o incomodo, mas vocês teriam alguma solução para isso? ou um ponto de partida para mim pesquisar, já estou sem ideias, já faz dias que estou pesquisando e não encontro uma solução.

Comment: @RafaeldeOliveira Bem, eu não sei. A única sugestão viável que eu poderia te dar é fazer o downloader rodar na máquina do usuário e você disponibilizar esse downloader. Quanto ao PHP, eu realmente não sei.